# The features don't appear at the first time in my exported PDF

Tags: pyqgis

My problem consists of exporting to PDF format. The first time I run my code (Text Editor of QGIS) the PDF only has the legend. But the second time, it has the features.
Changing the line of `QgsMapLayerRegistry` doesn't affect this issue.

What do you think the problem is?

Here is my code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import Qt

municipios = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE\\MUNICIPIOS.shp","Municipios","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(municipios)

el_renderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

#AJUSTE DE ZOOM EN UN CUADRO
rect = QgsRectangle(municipios.extent())
rect.scale(1.9)
#el_renderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
el_renderer.setExtent(rect)


composition = QgsComposition(el_renderer) 
composition.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
composition.PaperOrientation(QgsComposition.Portrait)

lst = [municipios.id()]  # add ID of every layer
el_renderer.setLayerSet(lst)
#el_renderer.setOutputSize(QSize(composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight()), composition.printResolution())
el_renderer.setOutputSize(QSize(210,297), composition.printResolution())
x, y = 0,0
w, h = composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight()
composer_map = QgsComposerMap(composition, x ,y, w, h)
composer_map.setOffset(-50, -60)
composer_map.setNewExtent(el_renderer.extent())
composition.addComposerMap(composer_map)
composition.addItem(composer_map)

print "\n QgsComposerMap funciona"

# LEGEND

legend = QgsComposerLegend(composition)
legend.model().setLayerSet(lst)
legend.setItemPosition(180, 230, True)
composition.addItem(legend)
print "\n leyenda actualizada"


#FINISH LEGEND

#la ultima parte


printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(210,297), QPrinter.Millimeter)
#printer.setOutputFileName("ROUTE\\my_pdf.pdf")
printer.setOutputFileName("ROUTE\\DATOS\\my_pdf.pdf")
#printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight()), QPrinter.Millimeter)
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
printer.setResolution(composition.printResolution())

pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
composition.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()


print "\n se ha exportado a PDF"
```